# Where can i find these two blocks in simulink?

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink

I'm currenlty using MATLAB R2018A for my graduation project. I'm searching for the two blocks in the image below:

[image: check image]

I can't find it in simulink library browser.

Comment: I'm guessing that you've already installed the Arduino Hardware Support Package? It doesn't come with Simulink by default.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the block, select "Library Link>Go To Library Link". It will take you to the block in the library.